# place label bottom of dynamic Imagebutton

Tags: css, asp.net, vb.net

I create an Imagebutton and label dynamically

```
Dim BtnRepName = New ImageButton
                    BtnRepName.Style.Add("margin", "17px")
                    BtnRepName.ToolTip = sdr("reportname").ToString().Replace(".rpt", "")
                    BtnRepName.Height = 100
                    BtnRepName.ImageUrl = "~\Images\reports-icon.png"
                    BtnRepName.Attributes.Add("data-toggle", "tooltip")
                    BtnRepName.Attributes.Add("data-placement", "top")
                    AddHandler BtnRepName.Click, AddressOf BtnRepName_Click
                    BtnRepName.AlternateText = sdr("reportname").ToString().Replace(".rpt", "")
                    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(BtnRepName)
                    Dim lblrepname = New Label
                    lblrepname.Text = sdr("reportname").ToString().Replace(".rpt", "")
                    lblrepname.Font.Bold = True
                    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(lblrepname)
```

but I don't know how to make `label` place the bottom of `Imagebutton`

I try to use `Style=position:absolute` but the result is really bad

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `position:absolute` along with `control.style("position") = "location"`; basically you have to determine the position of the image button then set the labels position to under that.